# how to give comma(,) separator as decimal separator in ios 6?

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c, web, ios6

In my app im using HTML page for taking the data from the user in that im taking an textfield with type number ,my problem is that after entering the number into the textfield click on done button data coming on textfield with comma (,) separator ,this one working fine in ios 5 but in ios 6 not coming ,please give a suggestion for getting comma  separator in ios 6 ?

```
function addCommas(nStr)
        {

            nStr = removeCommas(nStr);

            nStr += '';
            x = nStr.split('.');
            x1 = x[0];
            x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
            var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
            while (rgx.test(x1)) {
                x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
            }
            return x1 + x2;
        }
```

im using above code for placing comma,

Comment: Try to post the code what you have already done then we can able to find the issue.

Comment: above code returns the number with comma separator but that number not displayed in text filed,it display number  without comma separator.

Answer (score 1):

Dont try to create a custom method to handle number separator. IOS has built in methods for that and it works depending on the user Country.

You need to do something like this:

```
NSNumberFormatter *nf;
nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[nf setMaximumFractionDigits:2]; // to show only two decimal places
NSNumber *num =[nf numberFromString:@"123456.789"];
NSLog([nf stringFromNumber:num]);
```

Check [apple's doc for NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html), for more info and options.

Comment: :above code related to objective c functionality but my entire operations are done only by using  java script.

Comment: This doesn't actually turn on the comma. To do that you need to set `nf.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyleDecimal;` More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17262406/1161906).