# NSNumberFormatter with comma decimal separator

Tags: ios, objective-c, decimal, separator, nsnumberformatter

I tried to convert an NSString like "12000.54" into "12.000,54". I wrote an NSNumberFormatter instance.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@"."];
[formatter setDecimalSeparator:@","];
```

But when I NSLog this :

```
NSLog(@"%@",[formatter stringFromNumber:[formatter numberFromString:value]]);
```

It prints null value. If I change my comma with a point it's working correctly. I just would like to be able to put what I want for my separators field (comma, point, slash, etc ...) and I have different outputs : 12/000,54 12.000.54 12,000,54 for example.

Do you know how I can handle this ?

Comment: Perhaps I found the problem. I have to use another NSFormatter to make my numberFromString first. I voted for closing my post

Comment: Don't close it, enter the answer yourself and check it, others will have the same problem in the future.

Comment: Concur with @DavidH . The question is valid and complete with code and necessary information. I'm actually upvoting it :-)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So the question is valid : I'm answering it myself :)

I have a decimal value read from sqlite (e.g 12000 or 12000.54) directly transformed into NSString.
I have to use different separator at some point in my code.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@""];
[formatter setDecimalSeparator:@"."];

// Decimal values read from any db are always written with no grouping separator and a comma for decimal.

NSNumber *numberFromString = [formatter numberFromString:@"12000.54"]];

[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@" "]; // Whatever you want here
[formatter setDecimalSeparator:@","]; // Whatever you want here

NSString *finalValue = [formatter stringFromNumber:numberFromString];

NSLog(@"%@",finalValue); // Print 12 000,54
```

Problem solved.

Comment: You can also use `NSString`'s `doubleValue` property.

Answer (score 47):

I would recommend not hardcoding the separator to ensure the right separator behavior based on the iPhone locale setting. The easiest way to to this is:

**using objective-c**

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
numberFormatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];// this ensures the right separator behavior
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
numberFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = YES;

// example for writing the number object into a label
cell.finalValueLabel.text = [NSString StringWithFormat:@"%@", [numberFormatter stringForObjectValue:numberFromString]]; // your var name is not well chosen
```

**using SWIFT 3**

```
 let formatter = NumberFormatter()
 formatter.locale = NSLocale.current // this ensures the right separator behavior
 formatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
 formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true

 // example for writing the number object into a label
 // your variable "numberFromString" needs to be a NSNumber object
 finalValueLabel.text = formatter.string(from: numberFromString)! // your var name is not well chosen
```

and I would not use the var-name "numberFromString" because it is an `NSNumberFormatter` method.
Good luck!

Comment: "formatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal" was key for my case.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest solution I recently found is:

```
NSString *localizedString = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%@", @1234567];
```

Also works with ints:

```
NSString *localizedString = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%d", 1234567];
```

Verified in Xcode 6 playground. But docs say this function has always existed.

Answer (score 5):

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
numberFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = YES;
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
NSString *formattedNumberString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@122344.00];`
```

This wll fix your rounding up problem if you are dealing with decimal points.

Answer (score 3):

For currency use...

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()

// Produces symbol (i.e. "$ " for en_US_POSIX) and decimal formatting
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency

// Produces commas; i.e. "1,234"
numberFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
numberFormatter.groupingSize = 3
```

Example usage:

```
let value: Double = 12345.6789
numberFormatter.string(from: value as NSNumber)
```

yields...

```
"$ 12,345.68"
```

as one would expect