# Comma separated Number showing correctly on simulator but not on iPad

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-x

To show a comma separated number I set local as

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "en_US");
```

then compose a message

```
char msg[100]={0};
sprintf(msg,"Reach a score %'ld.",mission.param1);
mission.msg=msg;
```

Then I display this message as :

```
sprintf( msgStr,"%s",mission.msg.c_str());

_missionStatusLabel1=CCLabelTTF::create(msgStr, "MarkerFelt-Thin", 52 * _scaleY, CCSizeMake(1000 * _scaleX,0),
kCCTextAlignmentLeft);

_missionStatusLabel1->setPosition( ccp(_screenSize.width * 0.53f, _screenSize.height*0.704f) );
```

Problem is, on simulator it shows correct format like for 25000 it shows 25,000 but when I run on iPad(ios7) it simply show 25000 without comma.

what I may be missing ?

EDIT:

> Or How would you show a comma separated number ?

Comment: this isn't an answer to your question, but you should really avoid using literals like 0.704f and instead store them in a constant. Otherwise 1) If you want to change it you only have to do it in one place 2) It gives the value some meaning (i.e. SCALE_VALUE is easier to understand than 0.704f).

Comment: Check the result of setlocale (ensure the en_US is supported on the iPad)

Comment: @DieterLücking Thanks for pointing that out I checked for simulator it returns en_US but for iPad it returns null so what should I do now ?

Comment: @Eklavyaa Install it or use another

Comment: well it seems like a major problem what if the users don't have it installed on their devices, in that case it simply won't show comma.

Comment: @DieterLücking I just found that my device shows comma from other games like Temple Run. So not having locale for en_US is not the problem. I will just post the code which worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see In my code above I am setting locale using the c++ setLocale. But this code showed comma only in simulator but not actual device . So I tried NSNumberFormatter class and everything worked just perfect. I picked the code from [NSNumberFormatter with comma decimal separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123119/nsnumberformatter-with-comma-decimal-separator#answer-17262406) and just wrapped under c++ interface for use