# Convert dot to commas number format in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I am trying to convert a number from US to European format.

input: 34.24
output: 34,24

I tried by using NSNumberFormatter but is not working. Is there any way to do that?

```
NSString *dd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f",amountDouble];
NSNumberFormatter *formatString = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatString setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
formatString.locale = Locale.currentLocale; //europe locale
NSNumber *reqNumber = [formatString numberFromString:dd]; // returns nil
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123119/nsnumberformatter-with-comma-decimal-separator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSNumberFormatter with comma decimal separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123119/nsnumberformatter-with-comma-decimal-separator)

Comment: The solution doesn't solved my problem completely. Hardcoding the separator does not ensure the right separator behavior based on the iPhone locale setting. I want to convert it in only europeon locale, otherwise it should not convert.
input: 34.24 

US locale output: 34.24 and

Europe locale output: 34,24

Comment: So you want to only change it if the locale is European? In this case just test currentlocale to european locale  and if true apply the convert as in the other question

Answer (score 0):

Try following;

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init]; 
numberFormatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale]; 
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle; 
numberFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = YES;

NSString* str = [NSString StringWithFormat:@"%@", 
[numberFormatter stringForObjectValue:dd]];
```